# Showing Full Image in UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimageview, xcode6

I am using UIImageView to show an Image. But when image populates in ImageView it shows a part of Image (upper part ) not the full image, as image is large.
  I was wondering if there is any way to show full Image in ImageView without using scroll view so that user can have a view of full image at once without scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the content mode of the UIImageView. In the Attributes inspector you can change it, for example to "Scale to Fill".

You can do this by code too, for example, in Objective-C:

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
```

If you want to keep the aspect you could set it to `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`.

Comment: Not working @Dario.  Still showing only part of the image.

Answer (score 0):

`UIImageView` view has a property `imageView.contentMode`, which you can use to configure image displaying mode.

Answer (score 0):

It will work

`imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;`